# Drag & drop between Listbox items and chess board

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to find a way to Drag & drop between Listbox items and chess board using WPF. I have a listbox on the left and a chess board on the right. How can I drag an item then drag into one or more squares of the chess board. Then click to the square, some information about the items here will be shown. I appreciate it if someone can help me? Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this helps you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks,I think my big issue is how the item can hold more than one squares

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a way to get you in the right direction

http://johnnblade.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/drag-and-drop-grid-control-row-devexpress-wpf/

let me know may u have more questions

Comment: my sample is for a grid, but you can use it on other controls

Comment: Thanks,I think my big issue is how the item can hold more than one squares. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is wat i hv done ..but here i drag the files from desktop to my listbox

```
 ` public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CompositionTarget.Rendering +=new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);

        FileBoard.Drop += new DragEventHandler(FileBoard_Drop);
    }
```

`

when you drag element

```
 void FileBoard_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];



            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                _files.Enqueue(fi);
            }

        }


    }
```

create a list DATAinGrid

using CompositionTargetRendering u can deque the files

```
private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_files.Count != 0)
        {
            // Create a photo
            FileInfo fi = _files.Dequeue();

         }
   }
```

and then allocate the itemsource to ur board or chess box item...try modifying the code i think u will get it

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I found a KISS solution to this.

Create your chess board grid using TextBlocks or images in a grid.

Create a model for the data to be passed.

in the xml do this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myname" x:Uid="myname" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding myfield}" Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Square_Drop"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="myname" x:Uid="myname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding myfield}" Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Square_Drop"/>
//etc etc etc

<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" x:Uid="myListBox" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource myListBoxListItemStyle}" Margin="10" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="myField" 
                     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

I would strongly recommend you use a resource for the styling of the TextBlock/Image squares. (one for white, one for black!)

[Learn how here](http://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html)

Then in your c# behind you will need:

```
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myListBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
            myModel data = parent.SelectedItem as myModel;

            if (data != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Square_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MyModel data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyModel)) as MyModel;

        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;

        tb.DataContext = data;

        //Add any database update code here

        refreshInterface();
    }
```